# Función en MySql

Tags: mysql

estamos pasando funciones de SYBASE a MySQL.
Al crear la función no me da error donde declara la función y al ejecutar el script me da error de sintaxis (1046)
También me gustaría capturar una excepción que es SYBASE la toma como "sqlcode"
Os dejo la función por si me podéis echar una mano, gracias!

```
create FUNCTION f_obt_max_id_vis(pl_lin numeric)
RETURNS numeric


BEGIN
DECLARE ult_id numeric;
DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION

SELECT 
    MAX(ID_VIS)
INTO ult_id FROM
    vis_pac
WHERE
    ID_LIN = p_lin;

    #if SQLEXCEPTION <> 0 then 
     #  EXIT
    #end if;

    RETURN ult_id;
END
```

Comment: El error de sintaxis es por una cuestión de delimitadores. Prueba en este fiddle y verás como usando como delimitador // compila bien: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/07a909

Comment: En cuanto a capturar la excepción, creo que si simplemente quieres que se salga de la función cuando salte la excepción, conforme la tienes definida es suficiente. Puedes quitar lo que tienes comentado

Comment: Muchas gracias! Ya funciona

Comment: Por otro lado, en caso de que haya excepción, como muestro el error?

Comment: Pues ya depende pero si te refieres a mostrar un mensaje personalizado según el error que se produzca, debes añadir a la parte de declaración del controlador de excepción el mensaje a devolver: DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION SELECT 'Se ha producido una excepción en la consulta';

Comment: Muchas gracias!

Comment: ¿Te lo pongo como respuesta y la aceptas?

Answer (score 0):

Hay un error de sintaxis por una cuestión de delimitadores. Prueba en [este](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/07a909) fiddle y verás como usando como delimitador *//* compila bien

En cuanto a la excepción, si te refieres a mostrar un mensaje personalizado según el error que se produzca, debes añadir a la parte de declaración del controlador de excepción el mensaje a devolver:

```
DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION SELECT 'Se ha producido una excepción en la consulta';
```